# Django Migration Database Column Order

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, migration

I use Django 1.11, PostgreSQL 9.6 and Django migration tool. I couldn't have found a way to specify the column orders. In the initial migration, changing the ordering of the fields is fine but what about `migrations.AddField()` calls? `AddField` calls can also happen for the foreign key additions for the initial migration. Is there any way to specify the ordering or am I just obsessed with the order but I shouldn't be?

**Update after the discussion**

PostgreSQL DBMS doesn't support positional column addition. So it is practically meaningless to expect this facility from the migration tool for column addition.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no officially supported way to do this, because fields are supposed to be atomic and it shouldn't be relevant. However, it messes with my obsessive-compulsive side as well, and I like my columns to be ordered for when I need to debug things in `dbshell`, for example. Here's what I've found you can do:

- Make a migration with `python manage.py makemigrations`
- Edit the migration file and reorder the `fields` in `migrations.createModel`

Comment: Thanks @FlipperPA, I think this is the closest that we can get. Unfortunately there is no way to make a work around for the column (field) additions. The newly added fields have to go to the end of the column list, don't they?

Comment: When adding columns, it depends on the backend database you're using. IIRC, PostgreSQL and SQL Server will only add columns to the end, unless you want to recreate the entire table and migrate all the data. In MySQL, you can run `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN column_name AFTER other_column_name`. Migrations could be modified for MySQL to use RAW SQL operations, but I wouldn't recommend it, as you'd be locked into MySQL down the road when you finally want to convert to PostgreSQL. :) Would a VIEW suffice in this case return the columns in the desired ordered, while leaving migrations alone?

Comment: Ah OK, so PostgreSQL doesn't support adding column to a specific position. Sounds it is better to live with this. Thanks!
 [https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/3277](another discussion on positional addition on postgresql)

Comment: "However, it messes with my obsessive-compulsive side as well" @FlipperPA - Totally me!

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about the PostgreSQL syntax but this is what it looks like in SQL after you have created the database. I'm sure PostgreSQL would have an equivalent:

ALTER TABLE `yourtable`.`yourmodel` 
CHANGE COLUMN `columntochange` `columntochange` INT(11) NOT NULL AFTER `columntoplaceunder`;

Or if you have a GUI (mysql workbench in my case) you can go to the table settings and simply drag and drop colums as you wish and click APPLY.