# Django Model Foreign Key Database Column Order

Tags: django, django-models

I use Django 2.1, PostgreSQL 10.5 and Django migration tool.

As can be seen in this post - [Django Migration Database Column Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45261303) there is no way to define database columns order after first migration.

But what about ForeingKey fields? They placed at end of database table even in first migration. In first migration, ForeingKey not contains in CreateModel section with other fields, ForeingKey placed separately with migrations.AddField at the end of file. At that if edit migration manually and move ForeingKey to CreateModel section - all works perfectly with any columns order.

So, the question - how save order of ForeingKey field in first migration automaticly (without manually editing migration file, just using manage.py makemigrations)?

Comment: Why does the order matter?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with editing the migration files manually right after they were created, if it really matters to you. Just make sure you edit them only before running `migrate` and you're good to go.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Technically - no matter, but aesthetically it may having some sense. In my case - i have table with many colums, and when i look at table, i want see foreign_key_id in beginning, and not scroll  to end.

Comment: @dirkgroten I understood, but in some cases, if i do many cardinally chages, for me easier delete migrations files, drop database tabels, and recreate all with manage.py makemigrations.

Comment: @dirkgroten Or if i creating new models or new app or new project - easy to forget about this not obvious behavior and what need fix it manually. And, in my opinion, it just not handy.

Comment: But again why does the order matter? Anyway, there's no way to do it via the standard `makemigrations` command. You might want to contribute to the Django project to add this feature, but I doubt many people need it.

Comment: @dirkgroten As i already said - technically no matter, just for esthetic. I just wanted to know possible it to do that at now. Maybe i missed something in Django documentation, or exist some undocument way to do that.

Comment: no way to do it. This goes into the very intrinsics of how `makemigrations` works, which you can look at in *django.db.migrations.autodetector.MigrationAutoDetector.generate_created_models*