# Control the order of the database columns before proceeding to makemigrations and migrate in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

Is there a way to control the database column ordering, directly *within* a Django [model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/)?

I know I can [manually edit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45261424/6630397) the migration file after `makemigrations` to adapt it to my needs, but is there a way to do so, prior to the `makemigrations` call?

This can be especially useful when initializing the database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Migration Database Column Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45261303/django-migration-database-column-order)

Comment: I purposefully added a link to that answer to show that I'm aware of that way of doing it; it's out of scope of the current question then.

Comment: Me closing as a duplicate of that question means the answer is still the same (As suggested by answer below)...

Answer (score 0):

There is still not a way, and this is by design. I wish there was a way!