# pgAdmin/postgresql is reordering my django model, prioritising character values over integer values

Tags: django, database, postgresql, pgadmin

It's not a huge issue that the columns have been re-ordered, but I would like to understand why pgAdmin / PostgreSQL has prioritised the ordered of fields which have a character value over an integer value?

See image of my django model below, and then an image of how it's structured in pgAdmin.

Is there a reason why it would re-order the model?

[image: Django Model:]

[image: pgAdmin DB titles reordered]
[image]

I was expecting the database to translate as per the order of the model

Comment: The model definition says nothing about the creation of the database tables. If anything should be approximately meaningful, then the migration files.

Comment: after creating the migration filed edit these files with preferred order, [django db column order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45261303/django-migration-database-column-order)

Comment: Thanks - I began the migration process again it restored the columns to the order I had intended